# Select tab programmatically custom tab bar ios

Tags: ios, swift3, custom-controls

I have used the following [tutorial](http://blog.adambardon.com/how-to-create-custom-tab-bar-in-swift-part-2/) to implement custom tabs in ios
Its working fine when i tap on any of the item. Now I want to move it Programatically. e.g. I received the notification form Firebase and want to open third tab. But I am getting nil. I have referenced the `MainTabbarController` instance in `appdelegate`. 
Here is what i have tried
In `CustomTabBar`

```
func customTapped(index :Int){
        animateTabBarSelection(from: selectedTabBarItemIndex, to: index)
        selectedTabBarItemIndex = index
        delegate.didSelectViewController(self, atIndex: index)
}
```

In `AppDelegate`

```
mainTabBarController?.customTabBar?.customTapped( index: 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link that you have provided along with the question, the following are the statements that I found to be responsible for switching the tabs

```
func barItemTapped(sender : UIButton) {
    let index = tabBarButtons.indexOf(sender)!

    animateTabBarSelection(from: selectedTabBarItemIndex, to: index)
    selectedTabBarItemIndex = index
    delegate.didSelectViewController(self, atIndex: index)
}
```

You can just modify this code as

```
func barItemTapped(sender : UIButton) {
    let index = tabBarButtons.indexOf(sender)!
    tabSelectedAt(index)

}

func tabSelectedAt(_ index:Int) {
 if selectedTabBarItemIndex != nil {
   animateTabBarSelection(from: selectedTabBarItemIndex, to: index)
  }
    selectedTabBarItemIndex = index
    delegate.didSelectViewController(self, atIndex: index)
}
```

So call the function `func tabSelectedAt(_ index:Int)` with the index of the tab which you wants to switch.

Comment: Did you try to call it from AppDelegate. I am getting nil. debugger says the CustomTabBar's selectedTabBarItemIden is nill

Comment: That means there isn't any previously selected item. So in that case you may not have to show the animation right. So you can skip that statement animateTabBarSelection if selectedTabBarItemIndex is nil.

Comment: putting that inside nil check  has no effect. Though the problem has been resolved. It was related to customtabbar instance. I made the reference to App Delegate before initializing customtabbar